# WatiN - Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate IE9 popup

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ssl-certificate, watin

I'm using watiN to test an ssl site on a test box with an un trusted certificate.

As a result I'm getting lots of popups from IE9 which I'm unsure how to handle with watiN.

The pink part of the picture is an iframe and the light blue part is the the host of the iframe. So it's only the iframe that isn't loading:

[image: Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate]

Now if i click "Show content" it then prompts me to reload the page and the content is displayed.

Does anyone know how to get around this in watiN?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to move the root certificate you're using into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities collection. Use CertMgr.msc to do this.

Comment: Thanks for this.. I had to create some new certificates so that the Subject of the certificate was the name of the machine serving the content.. then it worked :)

Answer (score -4):

Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate.

For more information, see "Certificate Errors" in Internet Explorer Help.